# Getting counts in MultiLabelBinarizer

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-manipulation

How can I get counts of items in MultiLabelBinarizer?

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform([(1,1,2), (3,3,2,5)]),columns=mlb.classes_)

Out[0]: 
   1  2  3  5
0  1  1  0  0
1  0  1  1  1
```

Instead of this, I want to get

```
Out[0]: 
   1  2  3  5
0  2  1  0  0
1  0  1  2  1
```

As 1 is repeated 2 times in row 1 and 3 is repeated 2 times in row 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

data = [(1,1,2), (3,3,2,5)]
pd.DataFrame([Counter(x) for x in data]).fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
    1       2   3       5
0   2.0     1   0.0     0.0
1   0.0     1   2.0     1.0
```